# Correction in sub folder names by replacing first two characters, if needed

Tags: powershell

I am using below Powershell script which successfully traverses through all my case folders within the main folder named Test. What it is incapable of doing is to rename each sub folder, if required, as can be seen in current and desired output. Script should first sort the sub folders based on current numbering and then give them proper serial numbers as folder name prefix by replacing undesired serial numbers.

I have hundreds of such cases and their sub folders which need to be renamed properly.

The below output shows two folders named "352" and "451" (take them as order IDs for now) and each of these folders have some sub-folders with a 2 digit prefix in their names. But as you can notice they are not properly serialized.

```
$Search = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test" -Filter "??-*" -Recurse -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

$Search | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\result.txt'
```

Below is my current output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-352\02-Proceedings 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-352\09-Corporate
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-352\18-Notices

C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\01-Contract
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\03-Application
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\09-Case Study
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\14-Violations
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\21-Verdict
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-352\01-Proceedings 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-352\02-Corporate
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-352\03-Notices

C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\01-Contract
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\02-Application
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\03-Case Study
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\04-Violations
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\Case-451\05-Verdict
```

Thank you so much. If my desired functionality can be extended to this script, it will be of great help.

Syed

Comment: how do you determine the sequence? will it always be the same sequence as the current file names OR will it be something based on the art after the number?

Comment: Hi Lee, Thanks for asking, Sub folder names after the number vary from case to case.

Comment: i was a tad unclear ... that isn't what i was asking about. [*blush*] i'm talking about the subdirs. is '02-Thing`, `04-OtherThing`, '17-AThing` supposed to be sequenced by the leading two digits OR by the text part of the dir name?

Comment: To be sequenced by the leading two digits. Anyways, solution by @AdminOfThings works fine. Thanks for your willingness to help though.

Comment: thank you for the added info ... i was quite curious. i'm glad to know that you have the solution you need! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following based on what you have posted:

```
$CurrentParent = $null
$Search = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test" -Filter '??-*' -Recurse -Directory | Where Name -match '^\d\d-\D' | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Parent.Name -eq $CurrentParent) {
        $Increment++
    } else {
        $CurrentParent = $_.Parent.Name
        $Increment = 1
    }
    $CurrentNumber = "{0:d2}" -f $Increment
    Join-Path $_.Parent.FullName ($_.Name -replace '^\d\d',$CurrentNumber)
}
$Search | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\result.txt'
```

---

I added `Where` to filter more granularly beyond what `-Filter` allows.

`-match` and `-replace` both use regex to perform the matching. `\d` is a digit. `\D` is a non-digit. `^` matches the position at the beginning of the string.

The [string format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) `-f` is used to maintain the 2-digit requirement. If you happen to reach 3-digit numbers, then 3 digit numbers will be output instead.

---

You can take this further to perform a rename operation:

```
$CurrentParent = $null
Get-ChildItem . -Filter '??-*' -Recurse -Directory | Where Name -match '^\d\d-\D' | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Parent.Name -eq $CurrentParent) {
        $Increment++
    } else {
        $CurrentParent = $_.Parent.Name
        $Increment = 1
    }
    $CurrentNumber = "{0:d2}" -f $Increment
    $NewName = $_.Name -replace '^\d\d',$CurrentNumber
    $_ | Where Name -ne $NewName | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
}
```

`$NewName` is used to simply check if the new name already exists. If it does, a rename will not happen for that object. Remove the `-WhatIf` if you are happy with the results.

Comment: Hi AdminOfThings, Thank you so much for your help. I ran the script and noticed "result.txt" is showing folders with desired serial numbers, however, actual sub folders kept within the two case folders have not been renamed. I am sure, I should have mentioned that my objective is also to rename the actual sub folders.

Comment: @SmIqbal I added a section for renaming.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. Works like a charm!